# What causes the ГѓВ pattern in this Mojibake?

Tags: mojibake

Google `ГѓВ` (UTF-8: `D0 93 D1 93 D0 92`) and you'll see a few examples of what seems to be Mojibake. A specific example is `ö` becoming `ГѓВ¶`.

What kind of encodings did the original `ö` go through to become `ГѓВ¶`? How would I figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When searching for `ГѓВ¶`, you can hit a website about Home Decor with a post titled [ГѓВ¤ГѓВЁГѓВ§ГѓВ ГѓВ©ГѓВ­ ГѓВЁГѓВ­ГѓВІГѓВҐГѓВ°ГѓВјГѓВҐГѓВ°ГѓВ®ГѓВў](https://web.archive.org/web/20210909233123/https://decoration.uzunerinsaat.com/%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2%C2%A4%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2%C2%A7%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2-%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%B3%D1%93%D0%B2%D0%B3/). Throwing this into an [online mojibake decoder/fixer](https://www.linestarve.com/tools/mojibake/?mojibake=%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%A4%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D0%81%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%A7%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92+%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%A9%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%AD+%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D0%81%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%AD%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D0%86%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D2%90%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%B0%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D1%98%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D2%90%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%B0%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%C2%AE%D0%93%D1%93%D0%92%D1%9E) gives us the string `äèçàéí èíòåðüåðîâ`, which at first looks like garbage, but the mojibake decoder also gives us a list of steps:

[image: Mojibake Decoder's list of steps]

We can follow these steps backwards with `ö` to see if we get the original `ГѓВ¶`:

1. Encode "ö" into UTF-8: `C3 B6`
2. Decode `C3 B6` into Latin-1: "Ã¶"
3. Encode "Ã¶" into UTF-8: `C3 83 C2 B6`
4. Decode `C3 83 C2 B6` into Windows-1251: "ГѓВ¶"

So, the `ГѓВ` (`C3 C8 C2`) pattern is caused specifically by characters in the `C3 80`-`C3 BF` range of UTF-8, or Unicode codepoints `00C0`-`00FF`.

Here is [a CyberChef for the forwards conversion](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Encode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27)Decode_text(%27ISO-8859-1%20Latin%201%20Western%20European%20(28591)%27)Encode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27)Decode_text(%27Windows-1251%20Cyrillic%20(1251)%27)&input=wMHCw8TFxsfIycrLzM3Oz9DR0tPU1dbX2Nna29zd3t/g4eLj5OXm5%2Bjp6uvs7e7v8PHy8/T19vf4%2Bfr7/P3%2B/woK9g) and [another for the backwards conversion](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=Encode_text(%27Windows-1251%20Cyrillic%20(1251)%27)Decode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27)Encode_text(%27ISO-8859-1%20Latin%201%20Western%20European%20(28591)%27)Decode_text(%27UTF-8%20(65001)%27)&input=0JPRk9CS0ILQk9GT0JLQg9CT0ZPQkuKAmtCT0ZPQktGT0JPRk9CS4oCe0JPRk9CS4oCm0JPRk9CS4oCg0JPRk9CS4oCh0JPRk9CS4oKs0JPRk9CS4oCw0JPRk9CS0InQk9GT0JLigLnQk9GT0JLQitCT0ZPQktCM0JPRk9CS0IvQk9GT0JLQj9CT0ZPQktGS0JPRk9CS4oCY0JPRk9CS4oCZ0JPRk9CS4oCc0JPRk9CS4oCd0JPRk9CS4oCi0JPRk9CS4oCT0JPRk9CS4oCU0JPRk9CS77%2B90JPRk9CS4oSi0JPRk9CS0ZnQk9GT0JLigLrQk9GT0JLRmtCT0ZPQktGc0JPRk9CS0ZvQk9GT0JLRn9CT0ZPQksKg0JPRk9CS0I7Qk9GT0JLRntCT0ZPQktCI0JPRk9CSwqTQk9GT0JLSkNCT0ZPQksKm0JPRk9CSwqfQk9GT0JLQgdCT0ZPQksKp0JPRk9CS0ITQk9GT0JLCq9CT0ZPQksKs0JPRk9CSLtCT0ZPQksKu0JPRk9CS0IfQk9GT0JLCsNCT0ZPQksKx0JPRk9CS0IbQk9GT0JLRltCT0ZPQktKR0JPRk9CSwrXQk9GT0JLCttCT0ZPQksK30JPRk9CS0ZHQk9GT0JLihJbQk9GT0JLRlNCT0ZPQksK70JPRk9CS0ZjQk9GT0JLQhdCT0ZPQktGV0JPRk9CS0ZcKCtCT0ZPQksK2).

Comment: In step #4, don't you mean Windows-1251?  Windows-1252 would be `ÃƒÂ¶`, not `ГѓВ¶`.

Comment: Good catch! Fixed.